# Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc - a flaw with Eclipse + Doclava

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

*There are quite a few questions with similar titles, but please read on as this is subtly different and I've not yet been able to find a solution in the many answers given to those other questions.*

Scenario:

I have an external JAR file with a separate HTML tree javadoc.  I have pointed Eclipse at the javadoc by completing the JAR's "Javadoc Location" in the build path dialogue.  The source is *not* available to Eclipse.

At first it looks like this is working fine.  If I hover over a **class** name (say, `Wibble`) the corresponding javadoc text pops up.

However, if I hover over a **method** (say the word *create* in `blah = Wibble.create();`), I get the pop-up "*...the Javadoc could not be found...*" which is confusing as it's just shown me the javadoc for the Wibble class.

Indeed, if I click on the icon within the pop-up to "Open Attached Javadoc in a Browser" it **correctly** opens the HTML and presents me with the text for the method that it just said it could not find!

Technical notes:

- My Eclipse version is Android Developer Tools, Build: v22.2.1, though this was happening on vanilla Eclipse before I updated to the ADT version.
- The javadoc is being generated by command line using the Doclava doclet.

Any suggestions about either what might be wrong in the javadoc, or in eclipse settings, or...?

`EDIT` In the course of subsequent experimentation I've found that this problem only occurs with a combination of Eclipse and javadoc generated by Doclava.  My pragmatic solution has been to generate the javadoc twice - once for human readability by using Doclava, and once for Eclipse readability using vanilla Javadoc.

If anyone knows these systems in depth I'd still love to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(In order to not leave this 'unanswered' now that I have a solution)*

In the course of subsequent experimentation I've found that this problem only occurs with a combination of Eclipse and javadoc generated by Doclava. My pragmatic solution has been to generate the javadoc twice - once for human readability by using Doclava, and once for Eclipse readability using vanilla Javadoc.

If anyone knows these systems in depth I'd still love to know **why**.